# An angle in a regular hexagon

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The marked angle is $60^\circ$.

But I wonder how the angle is found without using trigonometry.

[image: regular hexagon]

**EDIT.**

Extra question: How can it be proved that the line DI bisects the angle GIH?

Comment: Draw all the corresponding segments like the ones shown. ($C$ to the midpoint of $EF$, etc.) You'll get a symmetric figure that makes the calculation clear.

Comment: Alternative clue: the two quadrilaterals $ABCG$ and $BCDH$ are related how?

Comment: @Lubin I think it's the best way!

Comment: Oh, thank you. Your comments made me know my foolishness.

Comment: Not your foolishness, only your failure to look at the diagram in just the “right” way. In mathematics, two people look at the same phenomenon and see it entirely differently, *and prove entirely different theorems* about the phenomenon.

Comment: Please, think about the extra question.

Comment: Join  DI and extend it to J.  One more triangle like ABCQ, BCDH is thus made. Then it is easier to see bisection.

Comment: @Narasimham Sorry. I couldn’t catch your answer. Could you let me know it in detail?

Answer (score 0):

[image: hexagon[1]]

Could be a helpful construction. 60 deg is formed by rotation in symmetry, but DI not showing as bisector.